# Surprisingly large difference between tess4j and tess-two

Tags: tess4j, tess-two

tess-two seems to work pretty well when I know EXACTLY the location on screen where the text I want to OCR is.

Now I'm trying to scan for text against a busy background, and it's not working quite as well. 
[annotated android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfytW.jpg)

I built a stand-alone driver using tess4j and I get significantly better results:
[annotated desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Ij8.jpg)

I'm using `tess-two 5.4.1` and `tessj4 3.0`.

To scan I'm using `TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SPARSE_TEXT_OSD and` iterating using `TessBaseAPI.PageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE`

Any ideas why the results are so different? Does tess4j do some kind of preprocessing that is leading to a better result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting find. They use different versions of Tesseract, so that accounts for at least some of the difference.